# regression modeling - logistic

Tags: r, regression, logistic

My task is to run a logistic regression that models the probability that revenue is non-zero (in the
logistic regression parlance, a positive revenue is a success). Revenue variable is numeric and expressed in thousands of euro.
My code looks like this:

```r
my_data <- dataset
my_data$success <- ifelse(my_data$revenue > 0, 1, 0)
logistic_model <- glm(success ~ age + initial_capital + industry,
     data = my_data, family = "binomial")
summary(logistic_model)
```

Is it correct or there should be revenue variable itself when estimating the equation?

I want to know if the equation is correct, because it gives different values when I type either `revenue` or `success` in the equation

Comment: I agree that it’s primarily a methods question but since it is specifically about R, CV.com might refuse. The answer(I think) is the code looks fine and the a difference is to be expected. Go with the “success” as the dependent variable.

Comment: I thought it was more a conceptual question about whether revenue should be used as a predictor or not (I agree that it shouldn't ... it would be circular to have revenue as a predictor and "revenue equal to zero" as a response)

Comment: Due to the nature of a startup, many ventures in the sample have not yet started selling products or services;
therefore, their revenue is zero. That's the part of the task for estimating the regression

Answer (score 1):

I have my doubts that you should model revenue in this kind of binary way. However, if that if what you want to do, then the revenue value cannot be a predictor variable. When it comes time to make predictions in the future, you will lack the revenue value and be unable to make a prediction.

Comment: Due to the nature of a startup, many ventures in the sample have not yet started selling products or services; therefore, their revenue is zero. That's the part of the task for estimating the regression

Comment: @SallyNelly Does that oppose something I wrote?

Comment: Well, I didn’t understand your answer at all

Comment: In what kind should I model the revenue variable then? If it takes values from 0 to 1 since this is the logistic regression

Comment: If you use revenue as a predictor, what happens when you go to make new predictions?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct or there should be revenue variable itself when estimating the equation?

By this, I'm assuming you mean including the numeric value as a predictor.  Something like

`logistic_model <- glm(success ~ age + initial_capital + industry, data = my_data, family = "binomial")`

Clearly, were you to do this then the successes and failures would be completely separable and hence your model would fail to fit.

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly? I don’t understand a word from what u texted after my code

Comment: @SallyNelly if you include revenye in the model, your model will not work due to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics)